# CSS3: Inconsistencies with mix-blend-mode: screen across browsers?

Tags: css, cross-browser, webkit, mix-blend-mode

I'm trying to play around with `mix-blend-mode` and while most properties work, I get a lot of inconsistency with what the expected functionality of `mix-blend-mode: screen` is across all the modern browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

For Firefox (47.0) I get

[image]

IE Edge (25.10586.0.0)

[image]

And then both Chrome (51.0.2704.106 64-bit) and Safari (9.0)

[image]

I suspect because it is MDN, the expected output is what Firefox produces. [IE Edge makes sense because it does not support mix-blend-mode](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mixblendmode) so nothing happens.

I suspect it might be a webkit issue? Although I couldn't find anything about it. I also did turn on experimental web features from the `chrome://flags`

[image]

But it did not solve the issue. Is there a fix for this for Safari/Chrome? `mix-blend-mode` works for other properties i.e. `difference` but just have been having problems with what `screen` is supposed to output.